# Javascript - I have two event listeners which run the same global scope function, but one of them isn't working...why?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, addeventlistener

For a bit of context, I'm currently new to Javascript and programming in general. I'm currently making a to-do list using vanilla javascript.

I want the user to be able to add an entry by either clicking on the "+" button, or by pressing the enter key in the input field.

Definitions:

```
let count = 0;
let getAdd = document.getElementById('add')
let getBackground = document.getElementById('background')
let getInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('input')
let getItems = document.getElementsByClassName('item')
let getName = document.getElementById('name')
```

The "keypress" event listener is working, but the "click" event listener is not. Here's the part in question:

```
function addevent() {
    if (document.getElementById('name').value === '') {
        alert("You need to type something in the input field first!")
        return
    }
    if (getItems.length == 0) {
        count += 1;
        getBackground.innerHTML = ''
        getBackground.style = null;
        getBackground.innerHTML += '<div class="item"><div class="column input"></div><div id="spacer" class="column"></div><div id="bin" class="bin column row">X</div></div>'
        getInputs[count - 1].innerHTML = document.getElementById('name').value
        let heightplus = getBackground.offsetHeight;
        getBackground.style.height = parseInt(heightplus + 35) + "px"
        document.getElementById('name').value = ''
    }
    else {
        count += 1
        getBackground.innerHTML += '<div class="item"><div class="column input"></div><div id="spacer" class="column"></div><div id="bin" class="bin column row">X</div></div>'
        getInputs[count - 1].innerHTML = document.getElementById('name').value
        let heightplus = getBackground.offsetHeight;
        getBackground.style.height = parseInt(heightplus + 35) + "px"
        document.getElementById('name').value = ''
    }
}

getAdd.addEventListener("click", addevent(), false);

getName.addEventListener("keypress", function enter(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        addevent();
    }
}, false);
```

What am I missing here?

If you need any further info, let me know.

```js
let count = 0;
let getAdd = document.getElementById('add')
let getBackground = document.getElementById('background')
let getInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('input')
let getItems = document.getElementsByClassName('item')
let getName = document.getElementById('name')

function noitems() {
    if (count == 0) {
        getBackground.innerHTML = '<div class="start">Click on the <strong>+</strong> button to get started</div>'
    }
    else if (count == -1) {
        getBackground.innerHTML = '<div class="end">No more tasks? Happy days!</div>'
        count += 1
    }
    getBackground.style.paddingTop = "0px"
    getBackground.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 0px 0px"
    getBackground.style.backgroundColor = "white"
}

window.onload = noitems();

function addevent() {
    if (document.getElementById('name').value === '') {
        alert("You need to type something in the input field first!")
        return
    }
    if (getItems.length == 0) {
        count += 1;
        getBackground.innerHTML = ''
        getBackground.style = null;
        getBackground.innerHTML += '<div class="item"><div class="column input"></div><div id="spacer" class="column"></div><div id="bin" class="bin column row">X</div></div>'
        getInputs[count - 1].innerHTML = document.getElementById('name').value
        let heightplus = getBackground.offsetHeight;
        getBackground.style.height = parseInt(heightplus + 35) + "px"
        document.getElementById('name').value = ''
    }
    else {
        count += 1
        getBackground.innerHTML += '<div class="item"><div class="column input"></div><div id="spacer" class="column"></div><div id="bin" class="bin column row">X</div></div>'
        getInputs[count - 1].innerHTML = document.getElementById('name').value
        let heightplus = getBackground.offsetHeight;
        getBackground.style.height = parseInt(heightplus + 35) + "px"
        document.getElementById('name').value = ''
    }
}

getAdd.addEventListener("click", addevent(), false);

getName.addEventListener("keypress", function enter(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        addevent();
    }
}, false);

function doSomething(e) {
    if (e.target.id === "bin") {
        if (getItems.length == 1) {
            let clickeditem = e.target
            getBackground.removeChild(clickeditem.parentNode)
            count -= 2
            noitems();
        }
        else {
            let clickeditem = e.target
            getBackground.removeChild(clickeditem.parentNode)
            let heightminus = getBackground.offsetHeight;
            getBackground.style.height = parseInt(heightminus - 75) + "px"
            count -= 1
        }
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
}

getBackground.addEventListener("click", doSomething, false)
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap');
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Old versions of Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome, Opera and Firefox */
}
#title {
    font-size: 32px;
    margin-top: 1em;
    border: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #001F5F;
    width: 9em;
    margin-left: calc(50% - 4.6em);
    margin-right: calc(50% - 4.5em);
    text-align: center;
}
#inputfield {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
::placeholder {
    color: #E7E6E6;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
#name {
    height: 35px;
    width: 813px;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #001F5F;
    color: #E7E6E6;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 22px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px 2px darkgray;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 5px;
    border-color: #E7E6E6;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
#add {
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    background-color: #E7E6E6;
    color: #001F5F;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-style: bold;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px 2px darkgray;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
#add:hover {
    background-color:#001F5F;
    color: #E7E6E6;
}
#background {
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 2px darkgray;
    width: 900px;
    height: 0px;
    background-color: #E7E6E6;
    padding-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.start, .end {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 250px;
    font-size: 32px;
    padding: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#spacer {
    width: 10px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color:#E7E6E6;
}
.input {
    height: 35px;
    width: 808px;
    background-color:#001F5F;
    padding-left: 5px;
    border: 0px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #E7E6E6;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 2px darkgray;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.bin {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: normal;
    background-color: #E7E6E6;
    color:#001F5F;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.bin:hover {
    background-color:#001F5F;
    color: #E7E6E6;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 2px darkgray;
}
.item {
    margin-left: 32px;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 858px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.column {
    display: table-cell;
}
.thelist {
    margin-left: calc(50% - 450px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Oliver's To-Do List</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<h1 id="title">Oliver's To-Do List</h1>
<body>
<div class="thelist">
    <div id="inputfield">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Start typing here..."id="name">
    <div id="add">+</div>
    </div>
    <div id="background">
    </div>
</div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getAdd.addEventListener("click", addevent(), false);
```

should be

```
getAdd.addEventListener("click", addevent, false);
```

As per this example from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener :

```
// Function to change the content of t2
function modifyText() {
  const t2 = document.getElementById("t2");
  if (t2.firstChild.nodeValue == "three") {
    t2.firstChild.nodeValue = "two";
  } else {
    t2.firstChild.nodeValue = "three";
  }
}

// Add event listener to table
const el = document.getElementById("outside");
el.addEventListener("click", modifyText, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found out that within the getAdd event listener, the problem was the pair of brackets after the function name; once these are removed, it works just fine!

If anyone reading wants to add to this with their wisdom, knowledge and experience, or perhaps suggest any other improvements, please do!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you solved it. I just tried it out and modified something in the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Oliver's To-Do List</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<h1 id="title">Oliver's To-Do List</h1>
<body>
<div class="thelist">
    <div id="inputfield">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Start typing here..."id="name">
    <div id="add" onclick="addevent()">+</div>
    </div>
    <div id="background">
    </div>
</div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I added onclick="addevent()" , and It works